# Ethernet camera causing network driver buffer trashing / memory congestion?

Tags: networking, video, ethernet

We are running a high-res camera on a reserved, single 1Gb Ethernet port, connected to a Windows 10 machine. We let the camera run on Auto-triggering and so it takes and sends images as fast as it can - at least this is what I deduce from the observed network traffic: as soon as we start the camera, Ethernet utilization goes up to ~580Mb received on the Windows machine.

BUT: our image processing software (HALCON) does not grab every frame the camera sends. This isn't an issue for our task (nearly static scene, we only need a new frame when we have processed the old one after ~200 milliseconds) were it not for the fact that the attempt to grab the next image results in completely arbitrary delays, lasting from ~100 milliseconds to 20-30 seconds. The suspicious thing is that the first number of grabs runs smoothly and only afterwards we stumble around with unpredictable waiting times. Is it possible that these delays come from the application/network driver/os (which one I don't know) wading through the received data stream and throwing out aged packets? Is there a way to restrict Windows on one network interface to a few MB of receive buffer so that it wouldn't even try to build up many hundred MB of data stream which is thrown out anyway?

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry for the layman language, my background is embedded engineering.

PPS: Windows firewall is disabled for all ports

Comment: Sure, it's possible you have a glut of useless data pooling up somewhere, wasting resources. It's probably best to squelch it at the source rather than trying to find ways to purge it after it's been generated. Can you set your camera to 5 frames per second? If your image-processing software can only handle one frame every 200ms, that means you can only handle 5 fps. Or maybe don't use auto-triggering and instead set things up so your image processing software only triggers the camera to take/send a frame when the image processing software is able to handle a new frame.

Comment: Maybe try giving the capture software a higher priority. Also check and see if you are running on virtual memory, it could significantly impact performance. What resolution are the images per frame compared to the processing power of the machine? How much memory does this pc have?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart the machine is a 24 core monster with more RAM than is needed, so no, its definitely not the virtual memory or an underpowered machine. We are closing in on driver problems, as there are conditions where the camera delivers the advertised framerate, just not within Halcon.

Comment: Hmm, indeed that is what it sounds like. Lol 24 cores huh? Sounds rediculous. Good luck!